# Using Discriminating Union to implement basic Algebraic Simplification F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I'm using a Discriminating Union to define an algebraic expression, and then implementing a simplification function that performs basic Algebraic Simplification with a recursive Match-Case algorithm. I ran into a roadblock involving nested addition/subtraction/multiplication.

The issue is that the match-case for adding/subtracting/etc two or more nested `Expression` objects wont simplify all the way down to a single constant when it should. IE:

`simplify Add( Add( Const(1), Const(2) ), Add( Const(1), Const(2) ) )`

Returns an `Expression` object containing `Add(Const(3), Const(3))` when it should return one containing `Const(6)`

The following code will make what's happening very clear, for brevity I only included the cases for Addition, since the structure (and the problem) is identical for Subtraction and Multiplication:

```
// Expression type
type Expression =
    | X
    | Y
    | Const of float
    | Neg of Expression
    | Add of Expression * Expression
    | Sub of Expression * Expression
    | Mul of Expression * Expression

let rec simplify expr = 
    match expr with
    | X -> expr
    | Y -> expr
    | Const(n) -> Const(n)
    | Add(X, Const(0.0)) -> X
    | Add(Const(0.0), X) -> X
    | Add(Const(0.0), Y) -> Y
    | Add(Y, Const(0.0)) -> Y
    | Add(Const(n1), Const(n2)) -> Const(n1+n2)                  // PROBLEM_1
    | Add(expr1, expr2) -> Add(simplify(expr1), simplify(expr2)) // PROBLEM_2
```

The issue is that with the way it's currently structured, an input that matches `// PROBLEM_2` won't fully recursively simplify to a `// PROBLEM_1` case, even if `expr1` and `expr2` contain only `Const` values. As mentioned above, it eventually will return an `Expression` containing `-> Add(Const(n2), Const(n2))` instead of actually adding those final two values together as in `-> Const(n1+n2)`

What can I change about the way this is structured so that `Add(expr1, expr2)` will return a single `Const` in the event that that all sub expressions contain and are reducible to `Const` values, ie: that contain no variables or irreducible expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the last line changed to

```
| Add(expr1, expr2) -> simplify(Add(simplify(expr1), simplify(expr2)))
//                     ^^^^^^^^^                                     ^
```

is the only change needed?

Comment: This was exactly it. It has caused some other issues, but now I know what the issues was and can move forward.